# Passing values into a class created with Class.new

Tags: ruby, metaprogramming

I have a list of names and values I'm trying to read in and turn into classes so I'm using `Class.new`.

The end result I want is a number of classes that work as if defined like:

```
module MyMod
  class AA < Base
    def self.value
      value1
    end
  end

  class AB < Base
    def self.value
      value2
    end
  end

  ...
end
```

My current code looks like:

```
name = 'AA'
value = 'test'
MyMod.const_set name, Class.new(Base) do
  ???
end
```

Setting the name works great, but haven't figured out what I need in the block for get `value` in.  Calling `def` doesn't work because the closure for `value` gets lost.

I have managed to get things working with:

```
temp = const_set name, Class.new(Base)
temp.define_singleton_method(:value) { value }
```

However, it seems like there should be a way to do it with the block of `Class.new`.  Also, I'm really not sure `define_singleton_method` is actually putting the method in the right place.  It works in my tests, but I'm not sure if the method is actually where I think it is or somewhere else up the call chain.  I've tried various combinations of `class_variable_set`, `attr_reader`, `class_eval`, `instance_eval`, and others, but it got to a point where it was just guess and check.  I think I still haven't quite wrapped my head around metaprogramming :-/

Comment: Can you provide some context why you want to do this? Maybe there's another way. I love metaprogramming (I'm working with Smalltalk), but generating classes on the fly (I tried that) was rarely the optimal solution.

Comment: @ewernli I have a short list of valid name:value pairs.  I had created a class for them and kept the list of all the valid instances that were generated from reading a file.  I didn't want arbitrary instance being created so had a lookup method on that list instead of an initializer.  I was about to make another class that would encapsulate an "instance" of the first class storing a reference to it and some additional data.  Based on that naming I realised making classes and having actual instances of them might be better.  I think it models the domain well, but haven't considered performance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

if i correctly understood your question, this should work for you:

```
class Base
end

class AA < Base

  name = :Blah
  klass = self.const_set name, Class.new(Base)

  class << klass
    def value
      __method__
    end
  end

end

p AA::Blah.value
#=> :value
```

UPDATE: seems you want it defined in the block:

```
class Base
end

class AA < Base

  name = :Blah
  klass = Class.new(Base) do

    class << self
      def value
        __method__
      end
    end

  end
  self.const_set name, klass

end

p AA::Blah.value
```

you trying this:

```
const_set name, Class.new(Base) do
  ...
end
```

**it does not work cause the block is referring to `const_set` rather than to `Class.new`**

If you prefer `define_singleton_method` over `class << self`:

```
class Base
end

class AA < Base

  name = :Blah
  klass = Class.new(Base) do

    self.define_singleton_method :value do
      __method__
    end

  end
  self.const_set name, klass

end
```

And finally if you really want to define them at once, use brackets instead of `do...end`:

```
class Base
end

class AA < Base

  name = :Blah
  self.const_set name, Class.new(Base) {

    self.define_singleton_method :value do
      __method__
    end

  }

end
```

#### [Here](http://cibox.org/slivu/stackoverflow?lang=ruby&file=passing-values-into-a-class-created-with-class-new.rb&run=true) is a working demo

Comment: The crux of the solution was "it does not work cause the block is referring to `const_set` rather than to `Class.new`".  Thanks!  Refactorings have rendered the rest obsolete, but they were useful examples.

Comment: Further refactorings have rendered the rest of this very useful so thank you again!